# Got Struts Report when call Struts 2 Action using EJB 3.1 in JBoss 7.1.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2, jboss, ejb

I developed an EJB project and packaged it to jar file, then I create a Web Project with Struts 2.1.15.2, and placed the jar file in `WebRoot/WEB-INF/lib` directory. I plan to use `struts2-ejb3-plugin` to integrated them.But when I call execute method in `Action`, I got Struts problem report like this.

**Stacktraces:**

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.naming.NamingException: [ENCJNDIName = java:comp/env/edu.sdau.tobacco.action.common.LoginAction/userDAORemote][defaultJNDIName = /UserDAORemote/remote]?????????
    cn.agrael.struts.plugin.ejb3.StrutsEJBActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsEJBActionProxyFactory.java:33)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:553)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
    org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
    
javax.naming.NamingException: [ENCJNDIName = java:comp/env/edu.sdau.tobacco.action.common.LoginAction/userDAORemote][defaultJNDIName = /UserDAORemote/remote]?????????
    cn.agrael.struts.plugin.ejb3.AbstractApplicationServer.lookup(AbstractApplicationServer.java:107)
    cn.agrael.struts.plugin.ejb3.AbstractApplicationServer.fieldEJBAnnotationLookup(AbstractApplicationServer.java:30)
    cn.agrael.struts.plugin.ejb3.StrutsEJBUtils.fieldInject(StrutsEJBUtils.java:367)
    cn.agrael.struts.plugin.ejb3.StrutsEJBUtils.executeEJBInjectAnnotation(StrutsEJBUtils.java:270)
    cn.agrael.struts.plugin.ejb3.StrutsEJBActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsEJBActionProxyFactory.java:25)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:553)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
    org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
    
You are seeing this page because development mode is enabled. Development mode, or `devMode`, enables extra debugging behaviors and reports to assist developers. To disable this mode, set:

  struts.devMode=false
in your WEB-INF/classes/struts.properties file.
```

---

**this is the `struts2-ejb3-plugin.properties`:**

```
ENCPath=java:comp/env/
#ENCPath=ejb:/tobaccoWeb//
ejbContainer=cn.agrael.struts.plugin.ejb3.JbossApplicationServer
isParseResource=true
isParseEJB=true
earFileBaseName=
remote=remote
local=local
```

**and the `jboss-ejb-client.properties`:**

```
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false
remote.connections=default
remote.connection.default.host=localhost
remote.connection.default.port = 4447
```

**the `jndi.properties`:**

```
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do like that, instead create an Java EE project and add modules for EJB and Web separately. Once ear is being deployed JBoss will publish EJBs so their JNDIs will be accessible to the other modules, i.e. web module.